# Add form fields to django form dynamically

Tags: python, django, forms

Due to a BD design where depending on a value, the data is stored in different cells, I have to add form fields dynamically. I was thinking on this:

```
class EditFlatForm(BaseModelForm):


    on_sale = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    on_rent = forms.BooleanField(required=False)


    class Meta:

        model = Flat

        fields = ('title', 'flat_category', 'description')

        ...


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(EditFlatForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)


        flat_properties = FlatProperty.objects.all()

        for p in flat_properties:

            if p.type_value == 1:
                # Text
                setattr(self, p.title, forms.CharField(label=p.human_title, required=False))
            elif p.type_value == 2:
                # Number
                setattr(self, p.title, forms.IntegerField(label=p.human_title, required=False))
            else:
                # Boolean
                setattr(self, p.title, forms.BooleanField(label=p.human_title, required=False))
```

But the fields don't get added, what am I missing?

Comment: You certainly shouldn't be inheriting from BaseModelForm.

Comment: BaseModelForm is just a class I use to deal with labels, why shouldn't I use it?

Comment: perhaps ``self.fields[p.title] = forms....``? assuming that ``p.title`` is a string

Comment: @MihaiZamfir omg, of course, what was I thinking, cheers mate, add it as a response and I'll accept it but I assume this question is going to be very redundant

Comment: Apologies, I thought it was forms.BaseModelForm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `p.title` is a string variable, then this should work:

```
if p.type_value == 1:
     # Text
     self.fields[p.title] = forms.CharField(label=p.human_title, required=False))
```

Answer (score 6):

I recommend creating the form on the fly using `type`. So, you'll need to create a function that will generate a list of all the fields you want to have in your form and then use them to generate the form, something like this :

```
def get_form_class():
    flat_properties = FlatProperty.objects.all()
    form_fields = {}
    for p in flat_properties:
        if p.type_value == 1:
        form_fields['field_{0}'.format(p.id)] = django.forms.CharField(...)
        elif p.type_value == 2:
            form_fields['field_{0}'.format(p.id)] = django.forms.IntegerField(...)
        else:
            form_fields['field_{0}'.format(p.id)] = django.forms.BooleanField(...)
    # ok now form_fields has all the fields for our form
    return type('DynamicForm', (django.forms.Form,), form_fields  )
```

Now you can use `get_form_class` wherever you want to use your form, for instance

```
form_class = get_form_class()
form = form_class(request.GET) 
if form.is_valid() # etc
```

For more info, you can check my post on creating dynamic forms with django:
http://spapas.github.io/2013/12/24/django-dynamic-forms/

*Update* to address OP's comment (But then how to gain advantage of all the things ModelForm provides?): You can inherit your dynamic form from `ModelForm`. Or, even better, you can create a class that is descendant of `ModelForm` and defines all the required methods and attributes (like `clean`, `__init__`, `Meta` etc). Then just inherit from that class by changing the `type` call to `type('DynamicForm', (CustomForm,), form_fields  )` !

Comment: But then how to gain advantage of all the things ModelForm provides?

Comment: The dynamically created form ends up having a weird package name - if you try this `str(type('PostForm2', (Form,), {}))` - it returns `<class 'django.forms.widgets.PostForm2'>` - I feel like if the form is involved in an exception and shows up in a stacktrace, that'll really confuse people...